# How to return a value using a closure and assigning the value to a global variable

Tags: php, closures

What I am trying to achieve is to use closure to add the variables present in the array and assigning the result to `$mul` variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

Where have I gone wrong?

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5];
$mul =1;
$sum = function(){ 
        global $mul;
        foreach($array as $e){
          $mul+= $e;
        }
        return $mul;
      };
print_r($sum);
```

I have also tried this method but to no avail

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5];
$mul =1;
$sum = function() use ($mul){ 
  //global $mul;
```

// I Think the use statement above doesnt need the global here so I have commented the line above

```
foreach($array as $e){
      $m+= $e;
 }
   $mul= $m;
  return $mul;
};
print_r($sum);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5];
$mul =1;
$sum = function($arr) {
  $mul = 0;
  foreach($arr as $e){
    $mul += $e;
  }
  return $mul;
};
$mul = $sum($array);
print $mul;
```

When you declare the anonymous function, you still have to call it, which is something you weren't doing.

With all this, there is no need to specifically try and alter an outside variable, when you can simply pass your array of interest to the function, and then return the total sum directly to the calling block.

Comment: Please refrain from posting code-only answers, explain the issue and how you solved it.

Comment: @Darren Thank you so much for reminding me of that about half a second after i posted the answer and before i'd finished re-editing it. Very fast on the job.

Comment: Glad you have a sense of humour @pala_ :)

Comment: But you waste other people's time by quickly posting an answer which you know you intend to edit. The answer you posted was poor, and Darren's point was accurate! While you are frantically editing because you posted trying to be the first to answer (etc, want moar rep) people are viewing your answer. Myself, Darren, and likely the OP are 3 for starters. I have removed my downvote as it no longer stands. Had I not revisited, it would have remained, so best to avoid such "tactics" to be honest. Just write out your answer as needed. If others get in first well so be it. Simply make yours better.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I was getting so annoyed in the early hours of the morning as I am preparing for my exam. you guys are of great help ! My bad I forgot to invoke the function.

Answer (score 3):

No need for that `global` just add an argument on that function and pass it:

```
$sum = function($array, $mul){ // add the arguments needed
           //    ^       ^
    foreach($array as $e){
        $mul += $e;
    }

    return $mul;
};

$array = [1,2,3,4,5];
$mul = 1;

$result = $sum($array, $mul); // invoke function

echo $result;
```